# Issue with OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please refer the below code.

1) How can I insert `tias.InventoryID` in to `@TempIDList`. I am getting a syntax error saying `tias` is undefined.

2) I can avoid the issue in (1) by selecting it using the `SELECT` statement in the below code. But it opens another issue saying `Column Count Mismatch`.

How can I do both the tasks at the same time.

Task 1 : Inserting in to `[Product].[ProductSupplier]` table.

Task 2 : Inserting Tast 1's output in to `@TempIDList`

```
INSERT INTO 
[Product].[ProductSupplier](ProductID,SupplierID) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID,tias.InventoryID INTO @TempIDList(ProductID,InventoryID)
        SELECT 
            tias.ProductID
            ,tias.FromID
        FROM 
            [Product].[ProductSupplier] ps 
            INNER JOIN @TempInventoryStock tias ON tias.SupplierID = ps.ID 
        WHERE 
            tias.SupplierID <> tias.FromID;
```

Comment: You usually do it by abusing `MERGE` instead, as shown in the linked question. It's an unfortunate restriction on the `OUTPUT` clause for `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `tias` in OUTPUT clause:

```
INSERT INTO 
[Product].[ProductSupplier](ProductID,SupplierID) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID,INSERTED.InventoryID INTO @TempIDList(ProductID,InventoryID)
        SELECT 
            tias.ProductID
            ,tias.FromID
        FROM 
            [Product].[ProductSupplier] ps 
            INNER JOIN @TempInventoryStock tias ON tias.SupplierID = ps.ID 
        WHERE 
            tias.SupplierID <> tias.FromID;
```

Comment: I need to insert the Value from `@TempInventoryStock tias`. Not the value will be inserted to `[Product].[ProductSupplier]`